Rules to withdraw from blockchain
Can anyone verify if below can be true as I'm asked to hold money in my hot wallet in order to allow mirror process (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.x?topic=shipping-mirror-transaction-transformer-program) flow to be able to withdraw money?
Remittance Officer said: "As soon as the exact amount you need to have on your hot wallet account, the system will start the mirror transaction through the Blockchain - to your Cold Wallet, and from there you will have to move it yourself into your hot wallet account. When it arrives to the hot wallet you'll need to sell the Bitcoins for Euros and the Euros you will be able to make a bank transfer to your bank" - does it make sense? Can anyone send me the rules related to withdrawing money from blockchain? Thank you!

Sorry but I have no idea what that link is about. Couldn't even find the word "blockchain" anywhere there. What product are you talking about?
